# Array/list vs Dictionary (why we have them at first place)

Tags: arrays, dictionary, language-features, data-structures

To me they are both same and that is why i am wondering why we have dictionary data structure when we can do everything with arrays/list? What is so fancy in dictionaries?

Comment: It depends on what coding language you are using. What are you using? Python? HTML/CSS/JS? Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays provide random access of a sequential set of data.  Dictionaries (or *associative arrays*) provide a map from a set of keys to a set of values.

I believe you are comparing apples and oranges - they serve two completely different purposes and are both useful data structures.

Most of the time a dictionary-like type is built as a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) - this type is *very* useful as it provides very fast lookups on average (depending on the quality of the hashing algorithm).

Comment: @itsaboutcode yes, although the value accessed by key can be an array/list of more values.

Comment: A dictionary is very similar to an array. Whereas an array maps the index to the value, a dictionary maps the key to the value.

Answer (score 8):

Arraylists just store a set of objects (that can be accessed randomly). Dictionaries store pairs of objects. This makes array/lists more suitable when you have a group of objects in a set (prime numbers, colors, students, etc.). Dictionaries are better suited for showing relationships between a pair of objects.

Why do we need dictionaries? lets say you have some data you need to convert from one form to another, like roman numeral characters to their values. Without dictionaries, you'd have to hack this association together with two arrays, where you first find the position the key is in the first list and access that position in the second. This is terribly error prone and inefficient, and dictionaries provide a more direct approach.

Comment: so its like making things more "fancy"?

Comment: if you define fancy as "simpler, more reliable, easier to understand and work with", yes :D

Comment: The example which you have given can be implemented by by n*2 array? infect to me dictionary is n*2 array. My interpretation is right?

Comment: You are correct in the first part; An N*2 or 2-dimensional array is another way of storing key-value pairs. On the outside, a dictionary and a n*2 array do the same things. A dictionary just goes about the process differently internally.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion lies in the different naming conventions in different languages. In my understanding, what is called a "Dictionary" in Python is the same as "Associative Array" in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To build on what Andrew said, in some languages such as PHP and Javascript, the array can also function as a dictionary (known as associative arrays). It also comes down to loose v strict typing in the language.

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory do everything with dictionaries.
But do not forget that at some point the program runs on a real machine which has limitations due to the hardware: processor, memory, nature of the storage (disc/SSD) ...

Behind the scenes the dictionaries are often using a [Hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

In some languages you can choose between many different types of list/array and hash tables as there are many different implementations of those structures, each with advantages and disadvantaged.

Use an **array** when you work with a sequence of elements or need to randomly access an element at a given index (0, 1, 2, ...)

Use a **dictionary** when you have key/value format and need fast retrieval via key

If you want to understand more about these I recommend you learn more about [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure#Overview) as they are fundamental

NOTE: depending on the language the name of those structures may vary and is a source of confusion.

Comment: "depending on the language the name of those structures may vary and is a source of confusion." Yeah..... that makes wikipedia less helpful when everyone overides definitions with whatever data structure they want

Comment: @DanWhaley wikipedia suffers from the same problem indeed