# Sort method is running for ArrayList objects

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I wrote a code below,where i assigned ArrayList objects as as dictionary Items.But when I am running Sort method nothing happened.Is there any thing wrong I did in the below?

```
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ArrListChildDetails = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For Row=3 to ob1.Range.Rows.Couny

      For I=2 to ob1.Range.Columns.Count

      ArrListChildDetails.Add(ob.Cells(Row,I))  


      Next

      Dic(ob.Cells(Row,1))=ArrListChildDetails

    Next

    For Each D in Dic.Keys

       Dic(d).Sort() 'It is not working whereas Dic items are ArrayList object


    Next
```

Thanks,

Comment: @Tukai, can you show the illaborated view of your `ArrListChildDetails`? meaning, how the objects are structured within. Do you see that there two levels of sorting you would need here? Do you want to sort the dictionary or do you want to sort each `arrListChildDetails` or do you want to sort both?

Comment: @bonCodigo `do you want to sort each arrListChildDetails or do you want to sort both?`- Yes I want to sort the arrListChildDetails items only,as here each `arrListChildDetails` object is an `dictionary` Item. But I don't want to sort the Dictionay only therir `Items`.

Comment: @bonCodigo - **Do you see that there two levels of sorting you would need here?** - No I need only one level of `Sorting`.

Comment: @bonCodigo `dictionary` items are `ArrayList` object and those object before adding to the `Dic Keys` are being populated by the Excel rows values

Comment: @Tukai please check the answer and the details stated. You can sort each `ArrayList` before putting into the `Dictionary`. Please comment after trying it. :)

Comment: @Tukai [is this just useful or brilliant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords)? In a quest of getting a great feature :)

Comment: @bonCodigo hope you are fine! yes that is really awesome. i also facing same issue when i looking for answers that I know i have,but too much time it takes to find out. so your suggestions are really helpful!

Comment: @vbsolver then please vote up :) BTw long time no see, how is the project? all up and running?

Comment: Yeah really I would do that! my project phase - I delivered for all of your help. Now the next face is coming. I am involved in multiple projects - it is related to webpage scrapping. :)

Comment: @bonCodigo would you suggest any good Excel VBA books to learn?

Comment: There's Power programming with Excel VBA. It's like any other languages you can learn by yourself as long as your core-concepts are strong. If not you can catch those as well. But really you can look into Siddtharth Rout's, Chandoo's and Alen Brown's websites. Further Mr.Excel was my favorite resource site. I didn't know SO was so hyper and great till I became active in past 3 months. My SO account was idle...LOL and I used lots of online resources. There's more than enough to get you confident. But theory is a little important as well. Then try to do the questions here with correct answers

Comment: @bonCodigo save me here! my account got locked! can't post. Please raise a vote up to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321645/how-the-description-mentioned-hashmethods-work-in-ruby#comment19905772_14321645) please please do a vote up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you have two levels of sorting to do, if you really expect items to be sorted. It's not still clear what or at **which level** you need to sort.

1. Sort within each `ArrayList`

Try:

```
For Row=3 to ob1.Range.Rows.Couny
    Set ArrListChildDetails = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For I=2 to ob1.Range.Columns.Count     
       ArrListChildDetails.Add(ob.Cells(Row,I))  
    Next

    arrListChildDetails.Sort()
    Dic(ob.Cells(Row,1))=ArrListChildDetails

    '-- didn't use .Clear() so data & old Capacity will get wiped off as well
    Set arrListChildDetails = Nothing
```

2.To sort dictionary level, Sort within `dictionary` with your own sort() function:

`Dic(d).SortUserBuilt()`

**Note:**

AND **EACH ARRAYLIST IS NOT A DICTIONARY ITEM**, if so why would MSDN create two different object types?...[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). And [Array/list vs Dictionary (why we have them at first place)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695024/array-list-vs-dictionary-why-we-have-them-at-first-place)?

Comment: Is it possible `Dic(ob.Cells(Row,1))=ArrListChildDetails`? If possible after assinging them to the Item would it behave as simple 1D array or ArrayList? Can the ArrayList object be the Dic(K) Item?

Comment: Why would you care how they behave inside a `dictionary`? `Dictionary` doesn't care how data in `Arrays/ArrayLists` behave, it only cares how arrayList **S** behaves - not how their children behaves..., do you see the difference? And you need to `add ojects` into a dictionary with a `key`....

Comment: Can we pas `Dictionary` object as a Sub parameter? Please confirm!

Comment: @Tukai, just tell us what you really need here? You said you want to sort the `ArrayList`, so it's provided in the answer. And for the question of `sub parameter`, please try passing the parameter and see if it works. Then you know it can be or not... Parameter can be any object from `object` to `variant Array` to `integer`..

Comment: thanks for your confirmations! But I have a doubt if the `Dic(d).Sort()` is available.The Dictionary documentation i have this `Sort()` method is not mentioned there.

Comment: @Tukai, yes that's my mistake. `Sort()` has to be built by ourselves for `Dictionary`. However it doesn't seem that you need to sort your `dictionary`. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: then I will use `ArrayList` object as it has its own `sort` function.

Comment: @Tukai, well you can have `Dictionary` to hold all your `Arraylists` as it provides a key to refer to any specific item. You don't seem to need any sorting within ArrayLists, but within an ArrayList. So choose as it deems.

Comment: You catched me perfectly now! I am doing that only!