# When list will be faster than dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm writing app wherein time is important. I know that serching element in            `List<Value>` is slower than in `Dictionary<int,Value>`

```
class Value 
{
    String Name { get;set;}
    int ID {get;set;}
}
```

In the `Dictionary<int,Value>` a can put some `ID` int place of key and it will work. As I said serching in `Dictionary<int,Value>` is faster than  int `List<Valie>` ( O(1) for Dict and O(n) for List ) but adding new item is slower in `Dictionary<int,Value>` than in `List<Value>`. My question is how much slower?
How many diference must be betwen Serchng and adding frequency to make `List<Value>` more viable ?

Comment: Have you tried it and benchmarked it yourself? what was the results?

Comment: Pull out a Diagnostics.Stopwatch and see?

Comment: The key in a dictionary is a hash table.  So the time to retrieve for a binary hash is Log2(N).  A list the average time to get an item is N/2 when searching the list.

Comment: I depend on my theoretical knowledge and simple ask a question to confirm it or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array/list vs Dictionary (why we have them at first place)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695024/array-list-vs-dictionary-why-we-have-them-at-first-place)

Answer (score 0):

A HashSet < Value > provides a good compromise between Add and Search performances.

Answer (score -1):

I depends on the amount of entries you have. If you have only a few entries the List will be faster. It depends also on the Value you verify, if you verify a long string case insensitive in a List it will be slower tha verify an integer.