# Getting multiple outputs from my dictionary when I need only one

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Im having a little problem with only printing the corresponding abbreviation that is stored in a dictionary

```
user = input("Enter a Abbreviation: ")

dictionary = {"ADSL": "Application Programming Interface",
              "IDE": "Integrated Development Enviroment",
              "SDK": "Software Development Kit",
              "UI": "User Interface",
              "UX": "User eXperience",
              "OPP": "Object Oriented Programming"
              }

for x in dictionary:
    if user in x:
        print(user + ":" + " " + dictionary[x])

    elif x != dictionary:
        print("Abbreviation not found")
```

This is my output

```
Enter a Abbreviation: UI
Abbreviation not found
Abbreviation not found
Abbreviation not found
UI: User Interface
Abbreviation not found
Abbreviation not found
```

I only need the entered abbreviation key value not all the Abbreviation not found outputs, I hope this makes sense

Comment: what dont you just erase `elif` part? Maybe you can try to put what is your desired output, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good point of a dictionary is that is "indexed" so you don't need to find the key. You are following a array approach, and that is a wrong approach.

```
user = input("Enter a Abbreviation: ")

dictionary = {"ADSL": "Application Programming Interface",
              "IDE": "Integrated Development Enviroment",
              "SDK": "Software Development Kit",
              "UI": "User Interface",
              "UX": "User eXperience",
              "OPP": "Object Oriented Programming"
              }

if user in dictionary:
   print(user + ":" + " " + dictionary[user])
else:
   print("Abbreviation not found")
```

You can find more information about dictionaries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2695036/710162), [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Paper_1/Fundamentals_of_data_structures/Dictionaries) and on google. It is very important to know when to use arrays, dictionaries, lists, queues...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just this :

```
user = input("Enter a Abbreviation: ")

dictionary = {"ADSL": "Application Programming Interface",
              "IDE": "Integrated Development Enviroment",
              "SDK": "Software Development Kit",
              "UI": "User Interface",
              "UX": "User eXperience",
              "OPP": "Object Oriented Programming"
              }

for x in dictionary:
    if user in x:
        print(user + ":" + " " + dictionary[x])
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code and it works... Looks like you were checking all the options...

```
user = input("Enter a Abbreviation: ")

dictionary = {"ADSL": "Application Programming Interface",
              "IDE": "Integrated Development Enviroment",
              "SDK": "Software Development Kit",
              "UI": "User Interface",
              "UX": "User eXperience",
              "OPP": "Object Oriented Programming"
              }

found = 0
for x in dictionary:
    if user in x:
        found = 1
        print(user + ":" + " " + dictionary[x])

if found == 0:
    print("Abbreviation not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `dict.get`.

```
user = input("Enter a Abbreviation: ")

dictionary = {"ADSL": "Application Programming Interface",
              "IDE": "Integrated Development Enviroment",
              "SDK": "Software Development Kit",
              "UI": "User Interface",
              "UX": "User eXperience",
              "OPP": "Object Oriented Programming"
              }

result = dictionary.get(user.upper())
if result:
    print(user + ":" + " " + result )
else:
    print("Abbreviation not found")
```

You don't need to loop if you have the `key`